# How can I access this string in an stdClass object?

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I have an `stdClass` object which looks like this, I am trying to `echo` out the `steamid`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [steamid] => 76561198039509812
                            [communityvisibilitystate] => 1
                            [profilestate] => 1
                            [personaname] => Mike_Ock_Hurtz
                            [lastlogoff] => 1506899637
                            [profileurl] => http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198039509812/
                            [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg
                            [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg
                            [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg
                            [personastate] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Below is how I am getting the above:

```
foreach(updateBanList::readFile($file) as $steamprofiles){
    $steam = $steamUser->GetPlayerSummariesV2($steamprofiles[0]);
    print_r($steam);
    $players = $steam->response->players; 


}
```

To access the class so far I am have used

```
  $players = $steam->response->players;
```

This gets me to the last `array`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [steamid] => 76561198039509812
            [communityvisibilitystate] => 1
            [profilestate] => 1
            [personaname] => Mike_Ock_Hurtz
            [lastlogoff] => 1506899637
            [profileurl] => http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198039509812/
            [avatar] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg
            [avatarmedium] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg
            [avatarfull] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg
            [personastate] => 0
        )

)
```

I am trying to `echo` out the `steamid`, and I've tried a few things I know whatever it is i am doing is very simple, but its late in the day and I cannot figure it out.

If I try

```
$players->steamid;
```

I get the error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

If I try

```
$players['steamid'];
```

I get

> Notice: Undefined index: steamid

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try `$players[0]->steamid;`
Your object is inside an array

And if you are sure you will only get one object element in the array then use

```
$player = $steam->response->players[0];
```

`$player->steamid;` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the array.

```
$players = $steam->response->players;
$steamid = $players[0]->steamid;
```

or in one line;

```
$steamid = $steam->response->players[0]->steamid;
```

Now you can echo out you steamid:

```
echo $steamid;
```

If you have more than one Player in your array you have to loop thou:

```
 $players  = $steam->response->players;
 $steamids = array();

 foreach ($players as $key => $player)
 {
    $steamids[$key] = $player->steamid;
 }
```

Now you have an array of Steam IDs in `$steamids`. To echo it you can do:

```
foreach ($steamids as $key => $steamid)
{
    echo "Player " . $key . " has Steam ID:" . $steamid;

}
```

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Now that you understand that the next data type is an array and not an object, it is clear that doing something like `$players->steamid;` will cause an Error.

> Notice: Undefined index: steamid

`$players['steamid'];` cloud also not work because there is no Key/Index `steamid` in this array only one Key/Index with the value `0`

Answer (score 0):

`$players` is an indexed array of objects.

Try this:

```
print_r($players[0]->steamid);
```

Or this to dump all the array elements:

```
foreach ($players as $player) {
    print_r($player->steamid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$players` is array, You should access it's property on array element:

`$players[0]->steamid;`